# Proving the convergence of a bounded sequence in R

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Let $p \in X$. Show that $(d(x_n,p))$ converges in $\mathbb{R}.$

$\mathbf{My attempt}.$

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then, by our assumptions, there exists $N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $d(x_m,x_n) < \epsilon$ for all $n,m \geq N$. For this $N$ we have that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^N d(x_k,p)<\infty$ because otherwise for $p $ or some $x_k$ we have $d(x_k,p)= \infty$, $k=1,2,...,N$, which makes $d$ undefined, and so it is not metric, a contradiction. Similarly, $\max\{ (d(x_k,N)_{k=1}^{N-1}\}<\infty$. Put $\displaystyle M_1 = \sum_{k=1}^Nd(x_k,p), M_2= \max\{ (d(x_k,N)_{k=1}^{N-1}\}$. Now let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $n \geq N$, then we have 
\begin{align*}
 d(x_n,p)\leq d(x_n,x_N)+d(x_N,p) < \epsilon +M_1 
\end{align*}
if $n <N$, we have
\begin{align*}
 d(x_n,p)\leq d(x_n,x_N)+d(x_N,p) < M_2+M_1
\end{align*}
Now, take $M= \max \{\epsilon+M_1,M_1+M_2\}$, so we have $d(x_n,p)\leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$\
So $(d(x_n,p))$ is bounded, hence it has a subsequence that converges.

I am getting stuck here. I will really appreciate any further help.

Comment: This question is asking to show that $d(x_n,p)$ has a finite limit, not necessarily zero, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [reverse triangular inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality?wprov=sfti1), you get $$\vert d(x_n, p)-d(x_m,p) \vert \le d(x_n,x_m)$$ for all $n,m \in \mathbb R$.

As $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$, $d(x_n,p)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$. Hence it converges.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For any $x,y\in X$, we have $$|d(x,p)-d(y,p)|\leq d(x,y)$$ and remember that $\mathbb R$ is complete.